# Open a Window after alert call

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to open an HTML page as soon as someone presses alert OK button. Ihave tried all ways possible. What's wrong with my code?

This is my HTML part

```
<form class="form-signin"  >       
          <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Sign Up</h2><br/><br/>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="User name" required autofocus="" /><br/>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>   <br/>   

          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="create()" value="Create" />

        </form>
```

And this is the js script

```
function create()
{

    var un = document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value;
    var pass = document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value;
    if(un==null || un=='' || pass==null || pass=='')
    {
        alert('Enter user name and password');
    }
    else
    {
    UnArray.push(un);
    PsArray.push(pass);
    alert("New username is created");
    window.open("file:///C:/Users/mohammed.mohiddin/Desktop/Doctor.html");
    }
}
```

Any of the methods are not working.

Comment: you are using `window.open` wrong, use like method `window.open("https://www.google.co.in");`

Comment: window.open() is a function.  See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: @ArunKumar Thankyou It worked :)

Comment: Hey! There are a few worrying things here - using alerts is generally frowned upon since they block the UI ([modal dialogs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) are fine though!), window.open is often blocked by adblockers (consider a link in the dialog). Client side security is also frowned upon when not done by a security professional because it is tricky to get right (people are able to open the debugger easily and figure out what variables are stored). Perhaps none of the above applies to you! Just want to make sure you're aware of the potential pitfalls.

Comment: Does it give any errors?
Are you sure that execution reaches the `window.open()`?

Comment: @nikosfotiadis No. It works fine.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. I am not following the standards yet because this is just one basic HTML page.

Comment: I want to open it in the same tab. i tried window.open('file:///C:/Users/mohammed.mohiddin/Desktop/Doctor.html','_self');  but it didn't work. any suggestion?

Comment: To open something in the same tab - you can use `location.href = ` or something similar and not window.open. I just wanted to make sure you are aware of the implications - good luck and happy programming :) 

Also, consider investing time in improving your search skills on Stack Overflow - it's a huge time saver for me.

Comment: location.href is not working for my code